# Print Asterisk symbol in iPhone label

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I am trying to print ascii values in label on one of the iPhone Application i am working on.I want the output to be something like this.How do i do it?[image]

Comment: Why not just set the text to "Customer's First Name *"? Asterisk is Shift-8 on most QWERTY keyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myLabel.text = @"Cutomer's First Name*";
```

---

Edited for making different color text you can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/tree/master/TTTAttributedLabelExample). 
Below is the code

```
TTTAttributedLabel *label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
NSString* text = @"Cutomer's First Name*";
[label setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString){
    //NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString;
    NSRange whiteRange = [text rangeOfString:@"*"];
    if (whiteRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor range:whiteRange];
    }
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica Neue" size: 10];
```

Comment: Thank-you very much buddy:),i want the color of the asterisk red.How do i do that?

Comment: for making the asterisk red you have to take another label with font color red and text as `*`.

Comment: [checkout this example](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/tree/master/TTTAttributedLabelExample) hope it will help you.